# Localstorage in ionic version 3

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am working on Ionic 3.9.2 platform. I want to know about how to add the user details in localstorage in latest version. Localstorage is not working in this version.

Comment: I Hope u find a solution check this link https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/display-username-once-logged-in-exactly-like-conference-app/67121

Comment: Pro-tip: we ask that people asking questions make a substantial prior effort before asking a question, and then once they have done that, they evidence that effort in their question. This question was answered by a link from the manual, and so I think it can be regarded as off-topic. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use Localstorage directly, the data saved in it can get lost on updates.

Use [Ionic Storage](https://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/) instead. It is made specificly for Ionic and uses different backends that are really persistent. It also has a nice and simple API.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I added the storage to my project, but it showing an error like

"Typescript Error
Cannot find name 'storage'.
D:/Ionic/SimBing/src/pages/home/home.ts
  storage.set('uname', this.model.username);
alert(storage.get('uname'));
// this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);"
Can you please help me to solve the issue..

Thanks

Comment: Then you probably didn't do everything from the docs. Check again. Also, outside the constructor you have to use `this.storage`.